# Save/Delete to HealthKit With WatchKit and Widget (Today Extension)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, healthkit, today-extension

Here is a question that I know has an answer since I see apps that do this functionality. I have tried (writing directly, using background fetch) but nothing works. I found an app currently on the app store with the functionality that I am looking for. With Background Fetch set to OFF and main app NOT running in background. I go to the Widget and add an item. I open HealthKit and I see the data there as expected.

I would like to do the same for my app. I would like my today extension (widget) and/or WatchKit extension to write to the HealthKit store even when app is not running in background. 
Like I said I have tested an app that does this functionality even though in Apple documentation it says this:

> The HealthKit store can only be accessed by an authorized app. You
>   cannot access HealthKit from extensions (like the Today view) or from
>   a WatchKit app.
>
> Because the HealthKit store is encrypted, your app cannot read data
>   from the store when the phone is locked. This means your app may not
>   be able to access the store when it is launched in the background.
>   However, apps can still write data to the store, even when the phone
>   is locked. The store temporarily caches the data and saves it to the
>   encrypted store as soon as the phone is unlocked.

Any answers or insights are appreciated. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lehn0058's comment about authorization was correct. I had to request authorization explicitly from the WatchKit and Today Extension even though authorization was already given in the app. Afterwards both are able to write to the Health Store. The comment from Apple above only has to do with Reading from the Health Store and NOT writing to the Health Store. Here is some sample code for anybody else who gets in to the same problem. Thanks again.

In WatchKit InterfaceController.m

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];
    // Configure interface objects here.
    [[HealthKitManager sharedManager] requestHealthKitAccess];
}
```

In Today Extension TodayViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    [[HealthKitManager sharedManager] requestHealthKitAccess];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Health Data Store is indeed encrypted while the device is locked. Locked is defined as requiring a passcode on the device and the screen was turned off (so a passcode or touch id is required before you can get back to the main screen). While the store is encrypted it is not possible to read any data from it, no matter if the app is running in the background or not. Even setting up observer queries while the app is running will not allow it to continue to be read from. I imagine this level of protection is done simply using the Data Protection capability with the [NSFileProtectionComplete](https://angelovillegas.com/ios-data-protection/) option.

What HealthKit functionality have you observed in this other app? If it was displaying step and distance data, then they are likely getting this data directly from the pedometer ([CMPedometer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMPedometer_class/index.html)), which is not restricted when the device is locked.

Comment: Thanks lehn0058. I don't need to read the HealthKit just to write to it. The app that shows this functionality writes a food type from its widget. The main app is NOT running and background refresh is turned OFF. So I don't know how they are doing it.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Writing data is different. Your data should get written to a temporary store and imported into health kit when the device is unlocked. Are you still calling the HKHealthStore.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes? application.didFinishLaunchingWithOptions may not get called just with a background refresh method. Also, do you get any errors when calling this method and are debugging? You probably now this but you can simulate a background refresh on your device in Xcode: Debug -> Simulate Background Refresh

Comment: Thanks lehn0058 again. Could you elaborate on temporary store? I am currently using CoreData so my widget, watch and main app all write to this CoreData store. I could always send everything in that store to HealthKit but would need to open the app which I would like to avoid. I didn't call HKHealthStore.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes in my background fetch. That is an excellent idea. So I should authorize in the background fetch code? I can try this. No I don't get any errors, the data gets written to the Coredata but nothing happens to HealthKit probably because no authorization is given.

Comment: The HealthKit temporary store is all behind the scenes, its just how it lets you write to it even though it is encrypted. It sounds like the authorization is likely at least part of your issue, especially if the app was closed and then that code is called.

Comment: I'll try this tonight and post my findings. However the other application is doing it without using background refresh since background refresh is off when it is run. I am wondering how this is done.

Comment: Thanks lehn0058 for your input. I had to explicitly request authorization from the extensions and now all works. See my answer. Thanks again.